# Why can't I access adminform.model_admin in my change_form admin template?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

When I try the following in a change_form template:

```
{{ adminform.model_admin }}
```

there seems to be an error when trying to render. I also created a simple_tag that takes the adminform as an argument, and then prints out adminform.model_admin successfully, so adminform definitely has the field model_admin defined.

Does anybody know what might be causing this error? I also set TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID to %s, and all that's output is "%s", whereas using any other invalid template string will actually output the string in place of the %s.